# How to pass object to local object method?

Tags: c++

I have class B and class A. In method of class B (let name it foo()) I have defined local object of class A. In class A I have method taking B object. How to pass B object to this method of class A when A object is local in method of class B. ?

```
class B {
public:
  void foo()
  {
     A a;
     a.bar(???); // want to pass B object?
  }
};

class A {
public:
  void bar(B& b)
  {
     ...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass the current instance of `B`:

```
a.bar(*this);
```

If you want a different instance:

```
B b;
a.bar(b);
```

If you want to pass a temporary, you need to modify `A::foo` to:

```
void bar(const B& b)
```

and then directly pass it:

```
a.bar(B());
```

Answer (score 4):

The `this` pointer is what you need, it points to the instance a member function is invoked on.

```
a.foo(*this); // dereference since 'this' is a pointer
```